# Unable to connect to the remote server while using Invoke-WebRequest in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am trying to download a file from the URL in the dropdown list using powershell. The URL is userid and password based. When i try to run the script I am getting the below error

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Unable to connect to the remote server
At C:\Users\x977887\Test.ps1:3 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -URI "https://my.vertexinc.com/downloads?
product_id=56149" -Proxy 'http://209 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: 
(System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], We
eption
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Below is the script i am using .

```
$securepassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("User 
ID", $securepassword)
Invoke-WebRequest -URI "https://my.vertexinc.com/downloads?product_id=56149" 
-Credential $credentials
```

I am new to this Power shell. Is something I am doing wrong in this? I am using version 5.0.10586.117

Comment: are you shure your proxy is reachable on http an port 443?

Comment: @vrdse That's the issue and I am not able to telnet that port from my server. Do i need to make any firewall changes to accommodate this?

Comment: is your goal to authenticate against the proxy or against the server serving the web page? your code says proxy authentication, your comment says the url is user/password based...

Comment: @Niels I have changed the code. It's against the server serving the Web page. I anything i need to add here?

Comment: What kind of output are you getting after this change? error? if so, you might want to verify that the website you're trying to access supports Basic authentication or requires another method.

Comment: @Niels Here is the ouput i am getting 

Invoke-WebRequest : Unable to connect to the remote server
At C:\Users\x977887\Test.ps1:3 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -URI "https://my.vertexinc.com/downloads?product_id ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Comment: The problem is probably the authentication on the website. This would work if the other side uses basic authentication, but the website probably has something else. maybe you can ask them if they have an api available that you could connect to?